# python pandas dataframe differences

Tags: python, dataframe

comparing the parsed JSON with the table data in database. I was able to successfully compared the data but , below is the clarification/help:

```html
     eventtime        _merge
0    2019-09-01 02:02:01        both
1    2019-09-01 02:02:17        both
2    2019-09-01 02:02:22   left_only
```

so, the "_merge" column gives me if the data is matching for all rows.

1) if the output(_merge column) gives all records as "both", it should be a "Passed" case
2) if the output(_merge column) gives at-least one record other than "both", it should be a "failed" case.

```html
     df_values = final_list['_merge'].to_string(index=False)
      print (df_values)
      if 'both' not in df_values:
          print ("failed")
      if 'both' in df_values:
          print ("Pass")
```

above code isn't consistent for multiple cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'all' to check that all the values are equal to 'both' :

```
df_values = final_list['_merge']

if all([val == 'both' for val in df_values]):
    print('Pass')
else:
    print('failed')
```

This can be condensed to

```
    if all(final_list['_merge']=='both'):
        print('Pass')
    else:
        print('failed')
```